# MySQL Select distinct date query

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
code    date1               date2
393517  07/07/2016 00:00    08/07/2016 00:00
393517  07/07/2016 00:00    11/07/2016 00:00
393517  07/07/2016 00:00    12/07/2016 00:00
393517  07/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393517  08/07/2016 00:00    11/07/2016 00:00
393517  08/07/2016 00:00    12/07/2016 00:00
393517  08/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393517  11/07/2016 00:00    12/07/2016 00:00
393517  11/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393516  07/07/2016 00:00    08/07/2016 00:00
393516  07/07/2016 00:00    11/07/2016 00:00
393516  07/07/2016 00:00    12/07/2016 00:00
393516  07/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393516  08/07/2016 00:00    11/07/2016 00:00
393516  08/07/2016 00:00    12/07/2016 00:00
393516  08/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393516  11/07/2016 00:00    12/07/2016 00:00
393516  11/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
```

How do I Select only one row for each date1 where date2 is the most recent date?

So the final output would be:

```
code    date1               date2
393517  07/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393517  08/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393517  11/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393516  07/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393516  08/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
393516  11/07/2016 00:00    13/07/2016 00:00
```

In other words, I would only keep the highest value of date2 for each date1 and code.

Comment: The simplest use case of `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.date2 = (SELECT MAX(t2.date2)
             FROM Table1 t2
             WHERE t2.date1 = t1.date1 AND t2.code=t1.code)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you just want a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT code, date1, MAX(date2)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY code, date1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select code, date1, max(date2) as date2 from table group by code, date1
```